# Rotation trackball

Tags: animation

How can I disable trackball rotation in Blender other than pressing <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd> on my keyboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "*disable trackball rotation*"? Pressing `R`,`R` activates it.

Comment: Maybe you want to reset the rotation? Alt R